# Performing operations on large database size approx 50 GB on Sql Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I have a multiples database with a combined size of about `50GB`.

I have to perform various operations and display the result (Only Accessing or Joins, No update/delete/insert operations). The time taken to perform these operations is about 8 mins.

How to bring the time down to less than a minute.

I am using SQL Server 2012, Asp.Net for rendering data on webpage.

Comment: Your question is: "How can I make any operation faster by 8x?". There is no answer is that in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a multiples database with a combined size of about 50GB

Ok, so where is "large"? A LARGE database generally is assumed to e one that is larger than the memory of a lower end server. Whic these days happens to be around the 64gb mark. So, that are SMALL databases.

> I have to perform various operations and display the result (Only Accessing or Joins, No 
>   update/delete/insert operations). The time taken to perform these operations is about 8 
>   mins.

How long is a piece of string?

As in: WHAT opeations. How much data do they manipulate?

Basically:

- Either you made a gross mistake (i.e. missing / extremely bad indices) or
- You run totally inappropriate hardware, likely with extremely slow but large and cheap discs

Fix those issues. I have no problem selecting daa in TABLES that have more han a couple of hundred gigabyte in miliseconds (that is about 500 rows out f around 10 billion rows) because (a) I have appropriate hardware and (b) I have the right indices. I also regularly delete 64 million rows in less than a minute out of that table.

So, start baseline debugging. Look at the query plans, see whether you miss something, if the plan looks good revie the hardware. Databases are seriously IO bound and LOVE to be on SSD - which has around 100 TIMES The IO performance of a hard disc, and with a SMALL system like yours there is no problem having enough memory for aggressive caching.

Comment: For testing purposes i am using a system with 
**Intel Core i3, 4GB Ram, and a 500 GB 5400 rpm hard drive**

Comment: @SanchitPruthi As I said - pathetic hardware. Well, if you use a crappy system for testing purposes, expect crappy results. As a developer doing non trivial work you should have appropriate tools.

Comment: I updated my hardware and the results are satisfactory now

Answer (score 1):

TomTom got it. Databases are IO bound. You have too many unknown variables in this question for any valuable response to help.

50 Gb is not big. You should be able to join, update, delete, etc without any issues.. Even on a smaller machine. I think you're missing indexes.

I run a lot of smaller operations on my local server hosted on a similar laptop to yours. I say smaller operations, I'm still able to select, join, etc hundreds/thousands of rows in seconds. That tells me you're database is probably not designed correctly. This is the big debate between app devs designing databases to supplement their applications and sql devs designing databases to support their app dev team. To explain the basics, I could type all day. Make sure your database has primary keys, proper indexes, sufficient datatypes (not all varchar(max) columns).

http://architects.dzone.com/articles/20-database-design-best